# Flutter App Store Connect Upload issue: ERROR ITMS-90171 - Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: flutter

I've run into an issue when trying to distribute my Flutter app to the Apple App Store:

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'Media
>   Converter.app/Frameworks/Pods_Runner.framework/Pods_Runner' is not
>   permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries,
>   other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to
>   the Bundle Programming Guide at
>   https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on
>   the iOS app bundle structure.

I haven't come across any search results regarding this Error in combination with Flutter and I'm totally clueless as where to start looking for the source of the problem.

I'm using the following dependencies in my app:

- cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
- share: ^0.6.3+6
- flutter_ffmpeg: ^0.2.10
- file_picker: ^1.4.3+2
- image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
- path_provider:
  ^1.6.1
- flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
- modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
- flutter_document_picker: ^4.0.0
- device_info: ^0.4.1+5
- url_launcher: ^5.4.2

Can anybody help?

Thanks a lot in advance!!
Best regards
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just managed to get this uploaded to the app store. What did the trick for me was to **remove** the **Pods_Runner.framework** from

**Build Phases** -> **Embed Frameworks**.

Was already included in Link Binary with Libraries sections so it seemed obvious it shouldn't be in both of the sections.

Not an ios dev here, just playing with fluter so I'm still waiting to find if something else is broken or not. Good luck there

Comment: It's worth to mention, that flutter build will run `pod install` under the hood and this in fact recreates linking of `Pods.framework`. I had to use 'pod deintegrate' and rebuild whole pods structure from scratch.